# Ways to map geo-co-ordinates, for labeling data in another profile of lats and longs?

Tags: r, sas, mapping, geospatial

I have a list of latitudes and longitudes with locations, another list with lats and longs only. I need to map this other set to an approximation of locations from the first list. I tried geosphere in R but the data is too big, and I ended up getting an error message saying "Cannot allocate a vector of Size 718.5 GB"! Any ideas? The data we are looking at to map is just huge (close to 100M rows divided into 48 segments that needs to be mapped to a list of lats and longs which is approximately 80k records long...)

Comment: For each point, you could calculate which reference point is the closest and map it there. Finding all 80 k distances shouldn't take much computation time and since you could do this one line at a time, you could parallelize the hell out of it.

Comment: Wouldn't that be 80K x 100M rows to find the nearest point though? Which is something in the order of 1 trillion calculations?

Comment: You mention 48 segments. Is segment part of the analysis at all? If you are finding closest location match within a segment, that would decrease the number of comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of Roman Luštrik's idea, dividing this up into as small of chunks as possible is going to be your most ideal solution. Let's start by finding the closest point on a per-row basis, rather than trying to load them all into memory at once. This example will be a SAS-based solution.

This example can also be much more efficiently accomplished by traversing hash tables, but would be more complex to explain here. That can be parallelized as well. This way has medium efficiency, but is easier to follow. Let's use two example datasets for this:

**1. Mobile_Activity_3months_scrambled.csv** - http://js.cit.datalens.api.here.com/datasets/starter_pack/Mobile_activity_3months_scrambled.csv

500k rows. Let's consider this your big dataset.

**2. sashelp.zipcode**

41k rows. Let's consider this your small dataset.

**Goal: Map each data point to the closest city.**

To keep this as simple as possible, let's read just one row and match it to the nearest city. First, read in your data:

```
proc import 
    file='CHANGE DIRECTORY HERE\Mobile_activity_3months_scrambled.csv'
    out=bigdata
    dbms=csv
    replace;
run;
```

Next, we'll read in one row and calculate its geographic distance with all other lat/long pairs. We will do a cartesian product with this data using SQL.

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table nearest_point as
        select geodist(t1.lat, t1.lon, t2.y, t2.x) as Distance
             , t2.city as Nearest_City
        from bigdata(obs=1 firstobs=1) as t1
        CROSS JOIN
             sashelp.zipcode as t2
        where NOT missing(t2.x)
        order by Distance
    ;
quit;
```

The first observation in the output dataset is your closest distance.

Let's generalize this for multiple observations. Let's do it for 10 of them, but increase the efficiency a little bit. We don't need to output all 41k observations. We just need to output the observation with the smallest distance and append it to a master table. Add the `outobs=1` option to SQL.

```
%macro nearest_distance;

    %do i = 1 %to 10;
        proc sql outobs=1 noprint;
            create table nearest_point as
                select geodist(t1.lat, t1.lon, t2.y, t2.x) as Distance
                     , t2.city as Nearest_City
                from bigdata(obs=&i. firstobs=&i.) as t1
                CROSS JOIN
                     sashelp.zipcode as t2
                where NOT missing(t2.x)
                order by Distance
            ;
        quit;

        proc append base=all_nearest_points
                    data=nearest_point
                    force;
        run;

    %end;

%mend;
%nearest_distance;
```

Let's generalize it even more, and remove writing to the log to make it faster. Let's even pre-load our zip code data into memory, and do this for *all* observations. For the sake of testing an example, we will first force `bigdata` to be a maximum of 100 obs.

```
data bigdata;
    set bigdata(obs=100);
run;

%macro nearest_distance;

    %let dsid   = %sysfunc(open(bigdata) );
    %let n      = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid., nlobs) );
    %let rc     = %sysfunc(close(&dsid.) );

    proc printto log="%sysfunc(getoption(work) )\_tmp_.txt";
    run;

    %do i = 1 %to &n.;
        proc sql outobs=1 noprint;
            create table nearest_point as
                select geodist(t1.lat, t1.lon, t2.y, t2.x) as Distance
                     , t2.city as Nearest_City
                from bigdata(obs=&i. firstobs=&i.) as t1
                CROSS JOIN
                     sashelp.zipcode as t2
                where NOT missing(t2.x)
                order by Distance
            ;
        quit;

        proc append base=all_nearest_points
                    data=nearest_point
                    force;
        run;

    %end;

    proc printto log=log;
    run;

%mend;
%nearest_distance;
```

Next, let's parallelize it, and finish it all up. You can change the number of parallel sessions you would like to use with the `threads` option.

```
%macro nearest_distance(threads=5);

    /* Parallel submit options */
    options 
        autosignon=yes
        sascmd='!sascmd'
    ;

    /* Current session work directory */
    %let workdir = %sysfunc(getoption(work) );

    /* Total obs in big data */
    %let dsid   = %sysfunc(open(bigdata) );
    %let n      = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid., nlobs) );
    %let rc     = %sysfunc(close(&dsid.) );

    /* Load lookup table to memory */
    sasfile sashelp.zipcode load;

    /* Prevent writing to session log */
    proc printto log="%sysfunc(getoption(work) )\_tmp_.txt";
    run;

    /* Run in &threads parallel sessions */
    %do t = 1 %to &threads.;

        /* Divide up observations for each thread */
        %let firstobs = %sysevalf(&n-(&n/&threads.)*(&threads.-&t+1)+1, floor);
        %let obs      = %sysevalf(&n-(&n/&threads.)*(&threads.-&t.),    floor);

        /* Transfer primary session macro variables to each worker session */
        %syslput _USER_ / remote=worker&t.;

        /* Parallel calculations for data in memory */
        rsubmit wait=no remote=worker&t.;

            /* We are in a specific session, and must define this as a macro within the session */
            %macro thread_loop;
                %do i = &firstobs. %to &obs.;

                    /* Primary session library */
                    libname workdir "&workdir.";

                    proc sql outobs=1 noprint;
                        create table nearest_point as
                            select geodist(t1.lat, t1.lon, t2.y, t2.x) as Distance
                                 , t2.city as Nearest_City
                            from workdir.bigdata(obs=&i. firstobs=&i.) as t1
                            CROSS JOIN
                                 sashelp.zipcode as t2
                            where NOT missing(t2.x)
                            order by Distance
                        ;
                    quit;

                    /* Save to primary session library */
                    proc append base=workdir._all_nearest_points_&t.
                                data=nearest_point
                                force;
                    run;
                %end;
            %mend;
            %thread_loop;

        endrsubmit;
    %end;

    /* Wait for all workers to end */
    waitfor _ALL_;

    /* Unload zipcode data from memory */
    sasfile sashelp.zipcode close;

    /* Append all data to the master file */
    proc datasets nolist;

        /* Delete final appended output data if it already exists */
        delete work.all_nearest_points;

        %do t = 1 %to &threads.;
            append base =  all_nearest_points
                   data = _all_nearest_points_&t.
                   force
            ;
        %end;

        /* Remove tmp files */
        delete _all_nearest_points_:;
    quit;

    /* Restore log */
    proc printto log=log;
    run;

%mend;
%nearest_distance;
```

Comment: This is a great example.  Nice! I have a similar problem. Thanks